# Object.entries() not iterating through all values passed to it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend, state

I am calling alpaca api, and storing results in a state array. Shown here, but am having trouble iterating through the JS object an displaying it in another component. I'm only able to display the first key/value pair, but not the rest. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Clock. Js

```
const Clock = () => {
    const initialState = {
        timestamp: "",
        is_open: false,
        next_open: "",
        next_close: "",
}
    const [timestamps, setTimestamp] = useState(
        {
            timestamp: "",
            is_open: false,
            next_open: "",
            next_close: "",
        }
    )

    const clearState = () => {
        setTimestamp({...initialState});
    }
    
    const printState = () => {
        console.log("Current Time: ", timestamps.timestamp);

    }
    
    const fetchData = async() => {
        let result = await alpacaIdentifier.getClock();
        setTimestamp(result);
    }
    
    useEffect(()=> {
        fetchData()
    }, [])
    
    return(
        <div>
            <Button onClick={printState}></Button>
            <ClockComponent 
                timestamps={timestamps.timestamp.length > 0 ? timestamps : ' '}
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default Clock;
```

ClockComponent.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {timestamps, isOpen, nextOpen, nextClose} from '../historical/Clock.js'

const ClockComponent = ({timestamps}) => {
    console.log("test", timestamps)
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(timestamps)) {
            
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>Key: {JSON.stringify(key)}</p>
                    <p>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</p>
                </div>

            )
    }
}


export default ClockComponent;
```

The intended area for outputs is under 'Details'.
The output only returns the timestamp value/key. Not the rest of the items (is_open, nextOpen, nextClose). [image]

**What can I do to reformat this in order to make the API calls/data formatting easier, or at least get it to display the other values from the API endpoint.**

The API for reference is: https://alpaca.markets/docs/api-references/trading-api/clock/

Answer (score 0):

Try pushing the divs in the loop to an array in memory, then return the array after the loop completes. You cannot simply return each row from within the loop.